# C# SMO Select from Database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, smo

I have been racking my brain trying to figure out how to execute a SELECT from Table using SMO in C# and returning that value to a string item.

I have seen multiple posts of how I can run a SQL script from within C# which is not what I want to do.  Here is the code I have so far

```
 public static void GetDealerInfo()
    {
        Server databaseServer = new Server(dbServer);
        try
        {
            databaseServer.ConnectionContext.LoginSecure = dbSecure;
            databaseServer.ConnectionContext.Login = dbUser;
            databaseServer.ConnectionContext.Password = dbPass;
            databaseServer.ConnectionContext.Connect();


           sDealerName = databaseServer.ConnectionContext.ExecuteWithResults("USE DATABASE Select DataValue from TABLE where KEYField = 'DealershipName'").ToString();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (databaseServer.ConnectionContext.IsOpen)
            {
                databaseServer.ConnectionContext.Disconnect();
            }
        }
    }
```

I also have a string called sDealerName which is where I want to pull, all I am getting is 
sDealerName = System.Data.DataSet

Can anyone point me in the correct direction?

UPDATE:

Here is the code to get it going or at least what worked for me

```
 try
        {
            databaseServer.ConnectionContext.LoginSecure = dbSecure;
            databaseServer.ConnectionContext.Login = dbUser;
            databaseServer.ConnectionContext.Password = dbPass;
            databaseServer.ConnectionContext.DatabaseName = dbDatabase;
            databaseServer.ConnectionContext.Connect();

            DataSet dsName = databaseServer.ConnectionContext.ExecuteWithResults("Select DataValue from ABSetup where KEYField = 'DealershipName'");

            sDealerName = dsName.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();

            DataSet dsNum = databaseServer.ConnectionContext.ExecuteWithResults("Select DataValue from ABSetup where KEYField = 'ABOfficeCID'");

            sDealerNumber = dsNum.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
        }
```

Comment: You could experiment with 1 trip to the database with this code.  You'll just have to "pluck" the values from the dataset a little differently.                DataSet dsName = databaseServer.ConnectionContext.ExecuteWithResults("Select DataValue from ABSetup where KEYField IN ('DealershipName' , 'ABOfficeCID' ) ");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
DataSet ds = databaseServer.ConnectionContext.ExecuteWithResults("Select DataValue from TABLE where KEYField = 'DealershipName'");
```

The "USE DATABASE;", first, you may not need it.  Second it, if you mean "USE MyDatabaseName;" , try it with a semi colon after the name.

More important to your question : then do a

```
Console.Writeline (ds.GetXml );
```

You'll then "see" the DataSet, the DataTable, the row inside the DataTable from which to "pluck" your scalar value.

```
string value = string.Empty;

if(null!=ds) {
if(null!=ds.Tables) {
if(ds.Tables.Count > 0) {
if(null!=ds.Tables[0].Rows) {
if(ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0) {
if(null!=ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].Columns){
if(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].Columns.Count > 0)
{
value = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].Columns[0].Value;
}}}}}}}
```

"Count" may be "Length", I'm going from memory.

My code is untested from memory, so take it with a grain of salt.

Comment: There is a VB.NET example at this URL.  And it shows how to look at values in a non-strongly-typed dataset.  Conversion to C# would be trivial.    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms205775.aspx

Comment: Here is what I have                                                   <NewDataSet>                                                                         <Table>                                                                  <DataValue>INFO I NEED</DataValue>                                          </Table>                                                                       </NewDataSet>                                                              Am I on the write track?

Comment: Right, now you have populated dataset.  So you need to "pluck" the value.  I'll update my post.

Comment: Thanks grandaCoder I got the info I needed by using the following     sDealerName = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();

Comment: Ok.  You might consider...doing an EDIT (put at the bottom of your original post) your final code...for future readers out there.

Comment: Just keep in mind, without all the null and Count checks, if your query doesn't bring back anything...your code will bl0w up on you (throw an exception).

Comment: Thanks the product we use has to have these 2 values in order to run in the database so I am not to worried about it going BOOOM but thanks for the tip.

Comment: Ok....typically, you would do something like "throw new ArgumentException("Such and such key was not found in the database");..which will mean something besides "object was null" excepiton.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling ToString() on the object instance which is why you're getting the fullly qualified type name.

The value you're looking for will be inside a `DataTable` object within the `DataSet`.  Run you're code again and break on the sDealerName line.  Then using the magnifying glass tool click on that to open the dataset viewer and you'll be able to figure the rest out from there.